# ambiguity in header files while building android ICS

Tags: android, c, linux, build, android-build

Here is the problem:
msm_camera.h is present in the following paths

1. ./external/kernel-headers/original/media/
2. ./bionic/libc/kernel/common/media/
3. ./prebuilt/ndk/android-ndk-r4/platforms/android-8/arch-x86/usr/include/media/
4. ./kernel/include/media/

When I try building errors are thrown saying some definitions like "MSM_PMEM_VIDEO_VPE" are absent. When they exist in one of the paths for eg. ./external/kernel-headers/original/media/

So, I would like to know when a C source file is compiling and it has headers added in this way:

```
#include <media/msm_camera.h>
```

How do I figure out which path the header is being picked from? Is it from option 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Build logs cant seem to help as well. 
I don't want to add absolute paths in hundreds of files cos its definitely not the right way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that is that the Android platform is out of sync with the software interface the chip vendor is providing in the kernel.  msm_camera.h is one of the original headers and has changed over the Android releases.  'MSM' indicates the vendor chip set that the header file supports.

Not the best solution, but can you make the kernel-headers include path precede the others?